# Calling constructor with multiple arguments

Tags: c++, constructor, arguments

I have

```
Triangle::Triangle()
{
    A = NULL;
    B = NULL;
    C = NULL;
}
Triangle::Triangle(Point& X,Point& Y, Point& Z)
{
    A = new Point;
    *A = X;
    B = new Point;
    *B = Y;
    C = new Point;
    *C = Z;
}

and 

istream& operator>>(istream& in, Triangle& T)
{
    Point X,Y,Z;
    in>>X>>Y>>Z;
    Triangle T(X,Y,Z);  
    return in;
}
```

Where Point is another class which defines a point with coordonates X and Y.
I don't know how to call the constructor with multiple arguments in the overloaded function. Can you help me?

Comment: Any reason you're using pointers for the class's points and taking the constructor arguments by non-const reference?

Comment: You shouldn't use a constructor in that function, not if you're passing in a `Triangle` by reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
Point px;
Point py;
Point pz;
Triangle trig(px, py, pz);
```

`trig` will be the object, which is an instance of class `Triangle` and the above would call the constructor with 3 Point arguments.

Another way is for pointers:

```
 Triangle *pTrig = new Triangle(pX, pY, pZ);
```

In addition, I suggest, that this would be better:

```
Triangle::Triangle()
   : A(NULL), B(NULL), C(NULL)
{
}

Triangle::Triangle(const Point& X,const Point& Y, const Point& Z)
 : A(new Point(X)), B(new Point(Y)), C(new Point(Z))
{
}
```

Assuming that Point has a copy constructor.

You want to call it from inside the `operator>>` function to update argument T, but this won't work, because you cannot call the constructor on something that's already constructed. Instead, what you need is to implement an assignment operator. Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_%28C%2B%2B%29 for more information.

Then you can do `T = Triangle(X,Y,Z);`

To implement the assignment operator, you can do this:

```
Triangle& Triangle::operator= (const Triangle& other)
{
    if (this != &other) // protect against invalid self-assignment
    {
        if (A != NULL) delete A;
        if (B != NULL) delete B;
        if (C != NULL) delete C;
        A = new Point(other.A);
        B = new Point(other.B);
        C = new Point(other.C);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Assuming Point has copy constructors. To implement copy constructors, please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor

A copy constructor looks like the following, but you need to do it for Point:

```
Triangle& Triangle::Triangle(const Triangle& other)
  : A(new Point(other.A)), B(new Point(other.B)), C(new Point(other.C))
{
}
}
```

Comment: Ahh... now I understand... you want to call it inside the operator>> function. No... that does not work. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Great!!It's working and you've done the assignment operator function too. Great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The first two constructors are overrides for default constructor. The third function is operator overloading which overloads >> operator. You just need to create an object of Triangle class as follow:

```
Triangle tr(x,y,z);
```

or

```
Triangle* tr = new Triangle(x,y,z);
```

Where x, y, and z are objects of Point class.

By the way, as you can see in your operator overloading (the third function), you are already creating an object of class Triangle (Triangle T(X,Y,Z);).

Comment: Yes but the argument of the operator overloading is the first constructor and won't pass the correct values for X,Y and Z